# Changing opacity property and apply gradient to Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my MVC3 project (using Twiter Bootstrap) I have a page with two radio buttons. When hovering the mouse on the second one the view displays a Bootstrap tooltip. Additionally I have a JS function that change the CSS appearance of that tooltip turning it to yellow.

I would like to remove the transparency and apply gradient by adding some css properties to my JS function. Something like this:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#FCEEC1),color-stop(100%,#EEDC94));
```

I've tried a thousand ways and I cannot. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!!

My radiobutton:

```
<span class="radio-button-revoked" title="CAUTION! Selecting this option will cause the revocation of the order delivery">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, 0, new { style = "margin-top: 0px;" })</span><span class="text-error"><strong> Not delivered</strong>
</span>
```

My JS:

```
function changeTooltipColorTo(color, textcolor) {
    $('.tooltip-inner').css('background-color', color)
    $('.tooltip-inner').css('color', textcolor)
    $('.tooltip-inner').css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $('.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow').css('border-top-color', color);
    $('.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', color);
    $('.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow').css('border-left-color', color);
    $('.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow').css('border-bottom-color', color);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
    $('.radio-button-revoked').hover(function() {changeTooltipColorTo('#F89406','#404040')});
});
```

**UPDATE:** Almost solved. Set the gradient:

```
$('.tooltip-inner').css('background-image', '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#FCEEC1),color-stop(100%,#E4BF46))')
```

I noticed that i can play with the gradient by setting the value from 0.1 to 1:

```
$('.tooltip-inner').css('opacity', '0.1')

$('.tooltip-inner').css('opacity', '1')
```

But i cannot make it completely opaque :(

Comment: You can do this instead: $('.tooltip-inner').css({ 'background-color': color, 'color': textcolor, 'font-weight': 'bold' });

Comment: @karaxuna thanks but that only optimizes the existing JS code, does not resolve my problem.

Comment: I know it would not solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

bootstrap.css was overlapping the CSS style defined in the javascript, so I changed the opacity value in bootstrap.css but, is there any way to do it without modifying the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the opacity of the tooltip by using the identifier: .tooltip.in

So if you want it completely opaque just use:

```
.tooltip.in {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```